# After tika-core is upgraded from 1.26 to 2.1.0, TIKA no longer throws an exception when parsing encrypted documents in .doc format

Tags: apache-tika

After tika-core is upgraded from 1.26 to 2.1.0, no exception will be thrown for encrypted doc documents

```
protected boolean checkMsmime(InputStream stream) throws IOException, SAXException {
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        BodyContentHandler bch = new BodyContentHandler();
        try {
            new AutoDetectParser().parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
        } catch (TikaException e) {
            // doc Encryption protection
            if (e instanceof EncryptedDocumentException) {
                return true;
            }
            // office docx Encryption protection
            if (e.getCause() instanceof org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException) {
                return true;
            }
            log.error(e);
            return false;
        }catch ( IOException exception){
            System.out.println("exception exception1 "+exception);
        }catch (SAXException exception){
            System.out.println("exception exception2 "+exception);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In version 1.26 of tika, if the .doc document is encrypted, `AutoDetectParser().parse()` TIKA parsing will throw an exception, but after upgrading to 2.1.0, no exception will be thrown, and it is considered not an encrypted document.

Encrypted files in other formats can throw exceptions, only encrypted documents in .doc format no longer throw exceptions

Comment: We have a unit test for this: https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/main/tika-parsers/tika-parsers-standard/tika-parsers-standard-modules/tika-parser-microsoft-module/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordParserTest.java#L635 and all of our parsers in 2.x should now be throwing o.a.t.exception.EncryptedDocumentExceptions.  Please open an issue on our JIRA (especially if you can share a triggering file): https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I later found out that it was caused by the conflict of the project jar package after the upgrade, which has now been resolved